# Access Send Email with Attachment

Tags: ms-access, email-attachments

I am attempting to add an attachment to my email and have a little trouble. I am able to go through the process of sending the email but I am lost on adding an attachment. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 If DLookup("[ApplicationName]", "tblEMailSoftware") = "Outlook" Then

       'Populate table with list of all email recipients
        DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete * from tblEmailList;"
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblEmailList ( EmailAddress ) " & _
                     "SELECT tblEmailNotification.EmailAddress From tblEmailNotification WHERE ((tblEmailNotification.AlertType) = 'New Lab Charge Code') " & _
                     "GROUP BY tblEmailNotification.EmailAddress;"
          
       'Retrieve all E-Mail Addressess in tblEMailList
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        Set MyDB = CurrentDb
        Set MyRS = MyDB.OpenRecordset("tblEMailList")

       '--------------------------------------------------
       'Build the Recipients String
        With MyRS
            Do While Not .EOF
                strEmail = strEmail & ![EmailAddress] & ";"
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
       '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       'send e-mail
        With objOutlookMsg
            .To = Left$(strEmail, Len(strEmail) - 1)        'Remove Trailing ;
            .Body = "The New Charge Codes for Lab have been Attached:" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
                    strMessage & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
                    "DST System Admin"
                
            .Subject = "DST Alert - New Lab Charge Code(s)"
            .Send
        End With

        Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
        Set objOutlook = Nothing
            MyRS.Close
        Set MyRS = Nothing

        End If  '(end of using outlook code to send email)
```

End Sub